# Prevent the user from pressing Next without filling in the required information and showing an alert message in wizard form html and javascript valid

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, wizard

please help, because I am tired of editing and I have not been able to add JavaScript code to the existing code, as I want the user to fill in all the data in the first file dest until he moves to the next and an error message appears to him that he has to fill in the full name field or the submission field.
my code:

```
<div class="form_holder  direc">
<form id="msform" action="JoinUs.php" method="post" >

 <fieldset>

<div class="row rowINdata">
<div class="col-md-12 coldatatxt text_modify direc"> <span class="data-name">  fullname: </span> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 coldatainput"><div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "">
<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Your Name" id="fullname"   />
</div></div>
</div>

<input type="button" name="next" id="nextbtn" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>

<div class="row rowINdata">
<div class="col-md-12 coldatatxt " style="text-align:left; direction:ltr;"> 
<span class="data-name"> 
Introduce your self and talk about your hobbies  (20-50 Words) : </span></div>
<div class="col-md-12 coldatainput"><div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "">
<textarea name="about" class="input100 txtarea req"  id="about"   placeholder="Your Answer" >
</textarea>
</div></div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="next" />
</fieldset>

 <fieldset>
 <div class="row rowINdata">
 <div class="col-md-12 coldatatxt " style="text-align:left; direction:ltr;"> 
 <span class="data-name">Introduce your self and talk about your hobbies  (20-50 Words) : </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 coldatainput"><div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "">
  <textarea name="about" class="input100 txtarea req"  id="about"   placeholder="Your Answer" >
  </textarea>
   </div></div>
   </div>

<br>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="previous" />
<input type="submit" name="Send" class=" action-button" id="send" value="send" />
</fieldset>

</form>
</div>
```

js:

```
 $(function() {

 var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
 var left, opacity, scale; 
 var animating;



 $(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
next_fs.show(); 
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 1000, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
previous_fs.show(); 
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'left': left});
        previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
       }, 
     duration: 1000, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
$("#msform")[0].submit();
return false
})

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that is good:

```
$("#ButtonId").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

if ($("#InputBoxID").val() < 100) {
    $("#FormId").submit();
}
else {
    alert("your message");
}
});
```